# android - Action bar sherlock add unnecessary button

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i use action bar sherlock and i set custom layout in the menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_menu"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/b_menu"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_audio"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/audio_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/b_audio"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_mySong_details"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/my_song_properties"
    android:icon="@drawable/b_mysong"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

to control those items i use:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /** Create an option menu from res/menu/items.xml */
    getSherlock().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_tab, menu);

    /** Get the action view of the menu item whose id is search */
    View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.action_menu).getActionView();
    Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

for some reason the action bar add unnecessary item, does anybody knows how this case happene?

Comment: what does "unnecessary item" mean?

Comment: I think he is complaining about overflow button

Comment: could you post a screenshot to help us figure out what the buttons you were saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake: i remove the android:orderInCategory from all the items and it's ok now, i this case i don't need this option.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Action bar sherlock. So use SupportMenuInflater.

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
  com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
  }

  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle item selection
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.action_menu:
     // Intent i=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
      //startActivity(i);
      return true;
  }
  return false;
```

}